# How to change style on losing focus with Js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to perform validation on the input element once it loses focus and change the style of the element accordingly.
I created the following code using internet. But it doesn't work(when the element loses focus the style doesn't get applied). What am I doing wrong ? / Any alternate methods ?

```js
let inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
let validate = (event) => {
  let element = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
  element.style.border = "1px solid #ff0000 !important";
};
for (let i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++) {
  inputTags[i].addEventListener("blur", validate);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
<input type="text" id="c">
```

Comment: Please describe the observed versus the expected behavior. "Doesn't work" is not specific enough.

Comment: Why not use the CSS `:focus` pseudo-class?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen now check ?

Comment: @Pointy I want to validate the input and then change the style accordingly. Will I be able to do that with `:focus` ?

Comment: `let element = event.target` is sufficient. (Does the element have an `id` at all?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`border` is a [shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties). You can't have `!important` on it. You could have `!important` if you set `borderWidth`, `borderColor`, and `borderStyle` individually, but in general, avoid using `!important`.

Here it is without `!important`, but keep reading:

```js
let inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
let validate = (event) => {
    let element = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    element.style.border = "1px solid #ff0000";
};
for (let i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++) {
    inputTags[i].addEventListener("blur", validate);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
<input type="text" id="c">
```

---

A couple of notes about that code, though:

1. You don't need `let element = document.getElementById(event.target.id);`, [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) **is** the `input` element. That said, I normally suggest using [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) because it's the element you hooked the handler on (whereas in general, `event.target` might be a child element, though of course not in this case, since the elements are `input` elements and so they can't have children).
2. Rather than setting inline styles, I recommend using a class.

Here it is with those changes:

```js
let inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
let validate = (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.classList.add("validated");
};
for (let i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++) {
    inputTags[i].addEventListener("blur", validate);
}
```

```css
.validated {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

You might also look into using [HTML validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) and the [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) pseudo-class.